# Custom callback in Express.js get

Tags: node.js, express

I have a get in my app.js

```
app.get('/api/personnel', api.personnel);
```

that calls this function as a callback to load some data from mongo:

```
exports.personnel = function(req, res) {
  var docs;
  db.personnel.find(function(err, docs) {
    if (err) {
      logError(err);
    } else {
      res.json({
        personnel: docs
      });
    }
  });

};
```

That works just fine, but I'd really like to be able to call a callback for testing purposes  when the function is complete:

```
exports.personnel = function(req, res, callback) {
  var docs;
  db.personnel.find(function(err, docs) {
    if (err) {
      logError(err);
    } else {
      res.json({
        personnel: docs
      });
    }
    callback();
  });
```

`callback()` is empty when the function is called from the live application and gives me a error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

How do I go about having a get call my callback?

Comment: third arity in Express is always reserved for `next()` callback (as found in middleware)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just wrap that function to insert the additional function argument:

```
exports.personnel = function(req, res, callback) {
  var docs;
  db.personnel.find(function(err, docs) {
    if (err) {
      logError(err);
    } else {
      res.json({
        personnel: docs
      });
    }
  });
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

var callback = ...;
pp.get('/api/personnel', function(req, res) {
     api.personnel(req, res, callback);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

third arity in Express is always reserved for `next()` callback (as found in middlewares).
If you want to have "callback" but does not want to mess up with express, let's hack!

```
exports.personnel = function(req, res, callback) {
  var docs;
  db.personnel.find(function(err, docs) {
    if (err) {
      logError(err);
    } else {
      res.json({
        personnel: docs
      });
    }
    if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test')
      callback();
  });
```

then, when you want to test, `export NODE_ENV=test` in your shell

Comment: Express will still call the handler with three arguments, even if you don't declare a third one.

Comment: Thakk you @robertklep +1

Comment: But `callback` will still be the `next` callback passed by Express, not a user-supplied callback...

Comment: `if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test')`, which means in production, this function does not get called, and nothing harm done, and in (unit) testing, dev'ers directly test `exports.personnel`