# How to test an ExpressJS route and 'controller' separately

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, asynchronous, express

I have an Express route defined as follows (where `app` is my Express app):

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  var controller = require('../../app/controllers/experiment-schema');
  app.route('/api/experiment-schemas/random').get(controller.random);
};
```

In that 'controller' file, I have this method:

```
exports.random = function (req, res, callback) {

  ExperimentSchema.count({}, function (err, count) {

    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);

    ExperimentSchema.find({})
      .skip(rand)
      .limit(1)
      .populate('mediaPool', 'artist title label')
      .exec(function (err, schema) {

        res.json(200, schema);

        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
          callback();
        }
      });
  });
}
```

Here, `ExperimentSchema` is a Mongoose model. Since the controller method hits the database, I'm passing in a callback in my test so that I can wait for those database calls to return and verify the return value. I'm doing this based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352159/custom-callback-in-express-js-get).

When I go to test the route, I'm testing with `supertest`, actually making the HTTP call to the route. The problem is that when I do this, Express is injecting `next` as the third argument to my `random` method. Now, `callback()` aliases `next()`, and everything goes haywire. How can I test my route and my controller seperately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by refactoring the route to expect only the default parameters `req` and `res`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to test controller functions like that is to just mock the request and response data and export it to a test suite like mocha. Though it also seems like you will need to mock out your mongoose schema's as well. There is no easy way to test these components unless you want to mock the inputs for these functions.